# HTML Button works in Windows browser but not Android

Tags: android, html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

https://blendbee.com/shop/black-tea-blends/minty-black/

If you click any of the "Add to Cart" buttons for either Sample, 1/4 Lb, 1/2 Lb, a message appears at the top saying that the product was successfully added to the cart.

[image: Android screenshot]

But the blue "View Cart" button in the message does nothing in Android Chrome on my Samsung Galaxy S5. It works fine in Windows 8 Chrome though.

I viewed the HTML source on each device and in Windows I can see:

```
<div class="woocommerce-message"><a href="https://blendbee.com/cart/" class="button wc-forward">View Cart</a> "Minty Black" was successfully added to your cart.</div>
```

But in Android I can't see that HTML in the source, although the button is visible in the browser.

This is a strange one...any ideas?

Comment: are you enable javascript?

Comment: Yes, other JS on the site works.

Comment: no,I mean do you have this line of code webView.getSetting().setJavaScriptEnable(true);

Comment: I'm not sure where to look for that.

Comment: I am using jquery mobile and every thing fine.but i will research for other solution

Comment: did u find the solution?

Comment: Nope :(  Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS did the trick:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #shop-sidebar {clear:both}
}
```